RN One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
I'm upgrading my targetSdkVersion to 34
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 26
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        supportLibVersion = 34
    }

and I've run into this error when running the react-native app.
I've seen a lot of solutions online that suggest adding
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter, RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
But they don't mention where it needs to be added. I've only worked on the react-native side so it would help if I had more details about the Android specific updates.

I added the following to MainApplication.java file.
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

and before public void onCreate() in the same file,
  @Override
  public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
      return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
    } else {
      return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
  }

In android/build.gradle under dependencies
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")

In android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip

I also kept getting the error
couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
For which I had to upgrade react-native-reanimated to 3.5.4.
I also upgraded my react-native-screens to 3.22.0.
My other main library versions
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",

This fixed things for me

The expansion in the MainApplication.java was enough to solve the problem for me. Thanks

What I did to solve this is that I opened up the node_modules for my React Native project (code node_modules) and I searched for all the occurences of registerReceiver. Then I looked at the libraries in the search findings and like that I knew which libraries I have to upgrade. Most libs already made a release to support SDK 34, but I also found libs that did not: for these libs I used a patch-package to create a patch file where I added the corresponding flag myself to the registerReceiver call(s).

I initialized
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-native": "0.76.3",

with MainApplication.kt instead of MainApplication.java.
For me it looks like this
  override fun registerReceiver(receiver: BroadcastReceiver?, filter: IntentFilter): Intent? {
  return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
      super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
  } else {
      super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
  }
}

In gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.11.1-bin.zip

All works fine
